# Django (removal of .auth and .django tables that are created after migrate command)

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django.contrib.auth

I have these 10 tables in Django (6-Auth tables and 4 Django tables) I am not using these files in my production project, I thought of removing them but read that its not a good practice to remove. I am dealing with some million records(GET and POST operations), Will these tables effect my code performance in the long run?

I have Tried removing these tables but all of them are interlinked with foreign keys.

Comment: i don't think that these tables will affect performance, if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the Django tables can cause unexpected behavior. These tables are there for providing specific services.

Tables started with Django have specific role:

- DJANGO_ADMIN_LOG(maintain change log)
- DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE(maintain app mapping)
- DJANGO_MIGRATIONS (migration status and history)
- DJANGO_SESSION (django DB sessions)
- DJANGO_SITE (site details, including url, DNS etc.)

These tables are essential for Django to work properly.

Auth related tables such as

- AUTH_GROUP
- AUTH_GROUP_PERMISSIONS
- AUTH_PERMISSION

these tables maintain auth permissions, auth Group, and group permissions.
If you are not using Django Auth, Group or Permissions features you can delete it. But I suggest let it be.

These tables won't affect your code performance.